Error 43 with Nvidia card in passthrough, not the usual suspect
My video card is returning an error 43. It's an Nvidia Geforce 1060. I have never bothered to remove any of the passthrough workarounds I have amassed over the years, so it's not related to the passthrough itself as far as I can tell.
I use a shared memory module (shm) with this particular VM. I created a copy VM and started both at the same time. No issues at first. After a while however the computer froze (I was getting no sound, so this is just an assumption on my part) and upon reboot I got the error 43. I checked and as it turned out I forgot to remove the shm from the copy. Since this shm is used to pass video information between guest and host my assumption is it overloaded the module, though the copy VM should not have been sharing anything with it's configuration. Again, just a guess.
As far as I can tell, this is not a driver issue. Nor an issue with the host, as dmesg shows nothing of interest. There is an error in the dmesg output, but with virt-manager. I am assuming it's unrelated (virt-manager[22523]: segfault at 7fcf27054b0f ip 00007fcf2630a37f sp 00007fceebffdb60 error 4 in libpcre.so.3.13.3[7fcf262f6000+51000] [1253228.053547] Code: 41 0f b6 4f 01 c1 e2 06 81 e2 c0 07 00 00 83 e1 3f 09 ca b9 02 00 00 00 89 d5 4c 8d 25 2a 17 05 00 83 e2 7f c1 fd 07 48 63 ed <41> 0f b6 2c 2c c1 e5 07 01 ea 48 8d 2d 10 34 04 00 48 63 d2 0f b7). lspci as well as other utilities not only pick up the GPU but show it in a usable state (I will show only lspci):
# lspci -vv
82:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr+ Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 83
    NUMA node: 1
    Region 0: Memory at fa000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Region 1: Memory at 39ffe0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 3: Memory at 39fff0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Region 5: I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at fb000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [78] Express (v2) Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable+ Non-Fatal+ Fatal+ Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <1us, L1 <4us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 8GT/s, Width x16, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range AB, TimeoutDis+, LTR+, OBFF Via message
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 8GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete+, EqualizationPhase1+
             EqualizationPhase2+, EqualizationPhase3+, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [250 v1] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Max snoop latency: 0ns
        Max no snoop latency: 0ns
    Capabilities: [128 v1] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [420 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap- CGenEn- ChkCap- ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [600 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900 v1] #19
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: nouveau

82:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. GP106 High Definition Audio Controller
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr+ Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 10
    NUMA node: 1
    Region 0: Memory at fb080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [78] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 75.000W
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable+ Non-Fatal+ Fatal+ Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <1us, L1 <4us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM L0s L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 8GT/s, Width x16, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range AB, TimeoutDis+, LTR+, OBFF Via message
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [100 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap- CGenEn- ChkCap- ChkEn-
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

Though perhaps I missed something. The KVM logs show nothing of interest either, at least as I can tell:
LC_ALL=C \
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin \
HOME=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-35-Windows \
XDG_DATA_HOME=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-35-Windows/.local/share \
XDG_CACHE_HOME=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-35-Windows/.cache \
XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-35-Windows/.config \
QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=spice \
/usr/bin/kvm \
-name guest=Windows,process=qemu:Windows,debug-threads=on \
-S \
-object secret,id=masterKey0,format=raw,file=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-35-Windows/master-key.aes \
-blockdev '{"driver":"file","filename":"/usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd","node-name":"libvirt-pflash0-storage","auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"}' \
-blockdev '{"node-name":"libvirt-pflash0-format","read-only":true,"driver":"raw","file":"libvirt-pflash0-storage"}' \
-blockdev '{"driver":"file","filename":"/usr/local/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/Windows_VARS.fd","node-name":"libvirt-pflash1-storage","auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"}' \
-blockdev '{"node-name":"libvirt-pflash1-format","read-only":false,"driver":"raw","file":"libvirt-pflash1-storage"}' \
-machine pc-q35-5.2,accel=kvm,usb=off,vmport=off,dump-guest-core=off,kernel_irqchip=on,pflash0=libvirt-pflash0-format,pflash1=libvirt-pflash1-format \
-cpu host,migratable=on,kvmclock=off,hv-time,hv-relaxed,hv-vapic,hv-spinlocks=0x1fff,hv-vpindex,hv-runtime,hv-synic,hv-stimer,hv-vendor-id=itsamemario,kvm=off,pmu=off \
-m 12288 \
-mem-prealloc \
-overcommit mem-lock=off \
-smp 16,sockets=1,dies=1,cores=4,threads=4 \
-uuid f899a9da-5125-46d8-8f6b-53d6fb09d1e0 \
-smbios type=0,vendor=LENOVO,version=1.02,date=04/08/2012,release=10.22 \
-smbios type=1,manufacturer=Supermicro,product=X9DRD-L,version=1.0.0,serial=1233RE34WE43T,uuid=f899a9da-5125-46d8-8f6b-53d6fb09d1e0,family=X9DRD \
-smbios 'type=2,manufacturer=LENOVO,product=20BE0061MC,version=0B98401 Pro,serial=W1KS427111E' \
-smbios 'type=3,manufacturer=Dell Inc.,version=2.12,serial=65X0XF2,asset=40000101,sku=Type3Sku1' \
-no-user-config \
-nodefaults \
-chardev socket,id=charmonitor,fd=32,server,nowait \
-mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control \
-rtc base=utc,driftfix=slew \
-global kvm-pit.lost_tick_policy=delay \
-no-hpet \
-no-shutdown \
-global ICH9-LPC.disable_s3=1 \
-global ICH9-LPC.disable_s4=1 \
-boot menu=on,strict=on \
-device pcie-root-port,port=0x10,chassis=1,id=pci.1,bus=pcie.0,multifunction=on,addr=0x2 \
-device pcie-root-port,port=0x11,chassis=2,id=pci.2,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x1 \
-device pcie-root-port,port=0x12,chassis=3,id=pci.3,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x2 \
-device pcie-root-port,port=0x13,chassis=4,id=pci.4,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x3 \
-device pcie-root-port,port=0x14,chassis=5,id=pci.5,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x4 \
-device pcie-root-port,port=0x15,chassis=6,id=pci.6,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x5 \
-device pcie-root-port,port=0x16,chassis=7,id=pci.7,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x6 \
-device pcie-root-port,port=0x17,chassis=8,id=pci.8,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x7 \
-device i82801b11-bridge,id=pci.9,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x1e \
-device pci-bridge,chassis_nr=10,id=pci.10,bus=pci.9,addr=0x0 \
-device ich9-usb-ehci1,id=usb,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x1d.0x7 \
-device ich9-usb-uhci1,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=0,bus=pcie.0,multifunction=on,addr=0x1d \
-device ich9-usb-uhci2,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=2,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x1d.0x1 \
-device ich9-usb-uhci3,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=4,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x1d.0x2 \
-device ahci,id=sata1,bus=pci.10,addr=0x4 \
-device virtio-serial-pci,id=virtio-serial0,bus=pci.3,addr=0x0 \
-device ide-cd,bus=ide.1,id=sata0-0-1 \
-device ide-cd,bus=ide.5,id=sata0-0-5 \
-blockdev '{"driver":"file","filename":"/media/Windows.qcow2","node-name":"libvirt-3-storage","auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"}' \
-blockdev '{"node-name":"libvirt-3-format","read-only":false,"driver":"qcow2","file":"libvirt-3-storage","backing":null}' \
-device ide-hd,bus=sata1.0,drive=libvirt-3-format,id=sata1-0-0,bootindex=1 \
-blockdev '{"driver":"file","filename":"/media/Games.img","aio":"native","node-name":"libvirt-2-storage","cache":{"direct":true,"no-flush":false},"auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"}' \
-blockdev '{"node-name":"libvirt-2-format","read-only":false,"discard":"unmap","cache":{"direct":true,"no-flush":false},"driver":"raw","file":"libvirt-2-storage"}' \
-device virtio-blk-pci,bus=pci.4,addr=0x0,drive=libvirt-2-format,id=virtio-disk0,write-cache=on \
-blockdev '{"driver":"file","filename":"/media/Windows_Swap.qcow2","node-name":"libvirt-1-storage","auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"}' \
-blockdev '{"node-name":"libvirt-1-format","read-only":false,"discard":"unmap","driver":"qcow2","file":"libvirt-1-storage","backing":null}' \
-device virtio-blk-pci,bus=pci.5,addr=0x0,drive=libvirt-1-format,id=virtio-disk1 \
-netdev tap,fd=34,id=hostnet0 \
-device e1000e,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:d7:9c:d8,bus=pci.1,addr=0x0 \
-netdev tap,fd=35,id=hostnet1,vhost=on,vhostfd=36 \
-device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet1,id=net1,mac=52:54:00:f7:7f:51,bus=pci.2,addr=0x0 \
-chardev pty,id=charserial0 \
-device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 \
-device usb-mouse,id=input2,bus=usb.0,port=2 \
-spice port=5900,addr=127.0.0.1,disable-ticketing,image-compression=off,seamless-migration=on \
-device qxl-vga,id=video0,ram_size=67108864,vram_size=67108864,vram64_size_mb=0,vgamem_mb=16,max_outputs=1,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x1 \
-chardev spicevmc,id=charredir0,name=usbredir \
-device usb-redir,chardev=charredir0,id=redir0,bus=usb.0,port=1 \
-device vfio-pci,host=0000:82:00.0,id=hostdev0,bus=pci.10,addr=0x2,rombar=1,romfile=/usr/share/vgabios/geforce-gtx1060.rom \
-rtc base=2020-09-27,clock=vm \
-sandbox on,obsolete=deny,elevateprivileges=deny,spawn=deny,resourcecontrol=deny \
-object memory-backend-file,id=shmmem-shmem0,mem-path=/dev/shm/looking-glass,size=67108864,share=yes \
-device ivshmem-plain,id=shmem0,memdev=shmmem-shmem0,bus=pci.10,addr=0x1 \
-msg timestamp=on
2024-08-15 03:33:52.843+0000: Domain id=35 is tainted: high-privileges
2024-08-15 03:33:52.843+0000: Domain id=35 is tainted: custom-argv
2024-08-15 03:33:52.843+0000: Domain id=35 is tainted: host-cpu
char device redirected to /dev/pts/8 (label charserial0)

I have uninstalled both cleanly and otherwise the graphics drivers on the VM, rebooting and then reinstalling the drivers immediately afterwards. Tried using the troubleshooting tool. Checked the event viewer and although I am getting a "miniport driver failed to start service" error, checking this answer leads me to believe it's unrelated. I got the rom from the GPU and used the romfile option. Tried an older driver (though that caused a fail to boot screen).
The sound still works. The basic display driver still works. The only thing that no longer seems to work is the video card.
Honestly at this point I am out of ideas. I assume it will clear when I reboot. But not only do I not want to and feel like I should be able to fix inplace, but when I reboot I might as well get back to an OS migration I've been meaning to do and it would be nice not to have this particular sword hanging over my head.
XML:
<domain xmlns:qemu="http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0" type="kvm">
  <name>Windows</name>
  <uuid>f899a9da-5125-46d8-8f6b-53d6fb09d1e0</uuid>
  <metadata>
    <libosinfo:libosinfo xmlns:libosinfo="http://libosinfo.org/xmlns/libvirt/domain/1.0">
      <libosinfo:os id="http://microsoft.com/win/10"/>
    </libosinfo:libosinfo>
  </metadata>
  <memory unit="KiB">12582912</memory>
  <currentMemory unit="KiB">12582912</currentMemory>
  <memoryBacking>
    <allocation mode="immediate"/>
  </memoryBacking>
  <vcpu placement="static" cpuset="2-13,15-20">16</vcpu>
  <sysinfo type="smbios">
    <bios>
      <entry name="vendor">LENOVO</entry>
      <entry name="version">1.02</entry>
      <entry name="date">04/08/2012</entry>
      <entry name="release">10.22</entry>
    </bios>
    <system>
      <entry name="manufacturer">Supermicro</entry>
      <entry name="product">X9DRD-L</entry>
      <entry name="version">1.0.0</entry>
      <entry name="serial">1233RE34WE43T</entry>
      <entry name="uuid">f899a9da-5125-46d8-8f6b-53d6fb09d1e0</entry>
      <entry name="family">X9DRD</entry>
    </system>
    <baseBoard>
      <entry name="manufacturer">LENOVO</entry>
      <entry name="product">20BE0061MC</entry>
      <entry name="version">0B98401 Pro</entry>
      <entry name="serial">W1KS427111E</entry>
    </baseBoard>
    <chassis>
      <entry name="manufacturer">Dell Inc.</entry>
      <entry name="version">2.12</entry>
      <entry name="serial">65X0XF2</entry>
      <entry name="asset">40000101</entry>
      <entry name="sku">Type3Sku1</entry>
    </chassis>
  </sysinfo>
  <os>
    <type arch="x86_64" machine="pc-q35-5.2">hvm</type>
    <loader readonly="yes" type="pflash">/usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd</loader>
    <nvram>/usr/local/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/Windows_VARS.fd</nvram>
    <boot dev="hd"/>
    <bootmenu enable="yes"/>
    <smbios mode="sysinfo"/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <hap state="on"/>
    <hyperv>
      <relaxed state="on"/>
      <vapic state="on"/>
      <spinlocks state="on" retries="8191"/>
      <vpindex state="on"/>
      <runtime state="on"/>
      <synic state="on"/>
      <stimer state="on"/>
      <vendor_id state="on" value="asdasdada"/>
    </hyperv>
    <kvm>
      <hidden state="on"/>
    </kvm>
    <pmu state="off"/>
    <vmport state="off"/>
    <ioapic driver="kvm"/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode="host-passthrough" check="none" migratable="on">
    <topology sockets="1" dies="1" cores="4" threads="4"/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset="utc">
    <timer name="rtc" tickpolicy="catchup"/>
    <timer name="pit" tickpolicy="delay"/>
    <timer name="kvmclock" present="no"/>
    <timer name="hpet" present="no"/>
    <timer name="hypervclock" present="yes"/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled="no"/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled="no"/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>
    <disk type="file" device="cdrom">
      <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
      <target dev="sdb" bus="sata"/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="1"/>
    </disk>
    <disk type="file" device="cdrom">
      <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
      <target dev="sdf" bus="sata"/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="5"/>
    </disk>
    <disk type="file" device="disk">
      <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2"/>
      <source file="/media/Windows.qcow2"/>
      <target dev="sdg" bus="sata"/>
      <address type="drive" controller="1" bus="0" target="0" unit="0"/>
    </disk>
    <disk type="file" device="disk">
      <driver name="qemu" type="raw" cache="none" io="native" discard="unmap"/>
      <source file="/media/Games.img"/>
      <target dev="vda" bus="virtio"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x04" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </disk>
    <disk type="file" device="disk">
      <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2" discard="unmap"/>
      <source file="/media/Windows_Swap.qcow2"/>
      <target dev="vdb" bus="virtio"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x05" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </disk>
    <controller type="sata" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1f" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="sata" index="1">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x0a" slot="0x04" function="0x0"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="0" model="pcie-root"/>
    <controller type="pci" index="1" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="1" port="0x10"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x0" multifunction="on"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="2" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="2" port="0x11"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="3" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="3" port="0x12"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="4" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="4" port="0x13"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x3"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="5" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="5" port="0x14"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x4"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="6" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="6" port="0x15"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x5"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="7" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="7" port="0x16"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x6"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="8" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="8" port="0x17"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x7"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="9" model="dmi-to-pci-bridge">
      <model name="i82801b11-bridge"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1e" function="0x0"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="10" model="pci-bridge">
      <model name="pci-bridge"/>
      <target chassisNr="10"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x09" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="virtio-serial" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x03" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-ehci1">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1d" function="0x7"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci1">
      <master startport="0"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1d" function="0x0" multifunction="on"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci2">
      <master startport="2"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1d" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci3">
      <master startport="4"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1d" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <interface type="direct">
      <mac address="52:54:00:d7:9c:d8"/>
      <source dev="eth1" mode="bridge"/>
      <model type="e1000e"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </interface>
    <interface type="network">
      <mac address="52:54:00:f7:7f:51"/>
      <source network="Host-Only"/>
      <model type="virtio"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x02" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </interface>
    <serial type="pty">
      <target type="isa-serial" port="0">
        <model name="isa-serial"/>
      </target>
    </serial>
    <console type="pty">
      <target type="serial" port="0"/>
    </console>
    <input type="mouse" bus="ps2"/>
    <input type="keyboard" bus="ps2"/>
    <input type="mouse" bus="usb">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="2"/>
    </input>
    <graphics type="spice" autoport="yes">
      <listen type="address"/>
      <image compression="off"/>
      <gl enable="no"/>
    </graphics>
    <video>
      <model type="qxl" ram="65536" vram="65536" vgamem="16384" heads="1" primary="yes"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x0"/>
    </video>
    <hostdev mode="subsystem" type="pci" managed="yes">
      <driver name="vfio"/>
      <source>
        <address domain="0x0000" bus="0x82" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
      </source>
      <rom bar="on" file="/usr/share/vgabios/geforce-gtx1060.rom"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x0a" slot="0x02" function="0x0"/>
    </hostdev>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="1"/>
    </redirdev>
    <memballoon model="none"/>
    <shmem name="looking-glass">
      <model type="ivshmem-plain"/>
      <size unit="M">64</size>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x0a" slot="0x01" function="0x0"/>
    </shmem>
  </devices>
  <qemu:commandline>
    <qemu:arg value="-rtc"/>
    <qemu:arg value="base=2020-09-27,clock=vm"/>
  </qemu:commandline>
</domain>

